# Pretty PHP URLs with nginx (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

I am having a lot of difficulty configuring nginx pretty URLs with PHP. I am trying to rewrite /verify/codehere (code example: dsifoj24234j) to verify.php?key=codehere

Here is my current configuration:

```
location ^/verify/(.*)$ {
    /verify.php?key=$1 last;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

.. It's not working, which brings me here. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
location ^/verify/(.*)$ {
    try_files /verify.php?key=$1 =404;
}

# or

rewrite ^/verify/(.*)$ /verify.php?key=$1 last;
```

Comment: It doesnt work, i believe i have already tried several variations of this code. My result is my index.php gets loaded without css or js.. Still need help :<

Comment: That's a different issue, could you check the error log for the missing assets